# How would I get this doctest to pass

Tags: python, doctest

I'm trying to get this doctest to pass by adding a function body but I don't know how to do that
can anyone help me

```
def reverse(s):

    """
    >>> reverse("happy")
    'yppah'
    >>> reverse("Python")
    'nohtyP'
    >>> reverse("")
    ''
    >>> reverse("P")
    'P'
    """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

Comment: Are you asking how would you implement a function that reverses a string? Wow that is a clever way around the longstanding expectation in StackOverflow that you can't ask people to do work for you you have to try and ask for help when you are stuck. All right I'll bite, what have you tried?

Comment: Strings in python can be reversed like this "happy"[::-1]

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is get this to pass through a doctest but I can't find the right way to write a function body to reverse to make the doctest pass.

Answer (score 0):

With the above edit the function should work as expected. The output for the same when executed would look like this

```
Trying:
    reverse("happy")
Expecting:
    'yppah'
ok
Trying:
    reverse("Python")
Expecting:
    'nohtyP'
ok
Trying:
    reverse("")
Expecting:
    ''
ok
Trying:
    reverse("P")
Expecting:
    'P'
ok
1 items had no tests:
__main__
1 items passed all tests:
4 tests in __main__.reverse
4 tests in 2 items.
4 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Comment: Don't edit the original question like that, it makes the question confusing for other readers.  Just include your answer in ... uh... your answer

Comment: sure wim, will do it the next time

Comment: sorry first time on here and first time using python, I did manage to get the answer! Thank You